# Can I change the rules for the url generation on new page

Tags: sharepoint-fields

Is it possible to alter the rules that are used to generate the url slug from the Page title when a new page is created? Currently it replaces spaces with hyphens but leaves special characters (such as apostrophe's) and leaves the capitalization intact. My organization would like to remove any special characters and change everything to lower case. Is this possible?

I know I can manually change it but my customers are complaining that they have to change it everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to create a workflow to start when a new item (page) is created and in the workflow, you can rename the file name (set name = abc- where you replace any unwanted characters with something else)